# Automating a form post in Firefox

Tags: http, forms, post, watir

I go to a web form, enter some info into a number of fields on the form, click the Submit button (which does a POST) and get results.  I do this frequently and would like to automate this process.  I mainly use Firefox.   I've looked at Watir but perhaps overkill for my needs.

Suggestions?

Comment: This is a superuser question, not a stackoverflow question.

Comment: @Jasper Watir implies coding the automation...

Comment: @Lucas Heneks: it still appears typically SU to me, but I may be wrong of course.

Comment: I'll give Watir a try.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watir or Watin are perfect for what you want, and aren't heavyweight.  I use them all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Watir's a great tool to get familiar with for UI automation. I don't quite understand the SU comment above, but it will work for what you're looking to accomplish. The additional side benefit is that you get to learn and/or work with Ruby. :)

Comment: SU is http://superuser.com/ (site like this but not about programming, for general computer related questions)

Answer (score 0):

have a look at simple to use [selenium plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2079/)

Answer (score 0):

Watir would handle this with ease. If you provide sample HTML and let me know what you want to do, I will create a Watir script.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps: http://interestingittips.wordpress.com/2010/08/23/hello-world/